# SSL certificate 'Resources unsecure'

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a site which has an SSL certificate. The certificate is all setup, but there is the big ugle red cross through the secure https:// because of resources that are not secure.

As it is a wordpress site, there are a few bits which are coming from other URL's - is there a way to get a complete list of these other resources that could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for finding Non SSL resources in web page (firebug like tool)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200932/tools-for-finding-non-ssl-resources-in-web-page-firebug-like-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's Developer Tools will tell you (I'm assuming you're using chrome because it's the only browser that I know of that has the cross through the https). Just hit ctrl-shift-j and reload the page. Each insecure resource should be logged in the console view.