# Tools for finding Non SSL resources in web page (firebug like tool)

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to find a non-SSL resource that is being loaded on my site. 
This happens occasional where one of us forgets to use the **https** version of a resource (like some js in a CDN).

My question is there any firebug-like tools to find these "Turds in the punch bowl"? I want my green padlock back :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides Firebug, which you've mentioned, you can use the developer tools in Chrome:

- Tools menu -> Developer Tools
- Go through the list of loaded resources in the Network tab

Alternatively, the HttpFox extension for Firefox can also be useful. It will keep logging the traffic even when you change pages, which may be useful in some cases.

(This is very similar to Firebug.)

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I was doing. It just gets painful going through a very long list of resources being downloaded :) I did contemplate using wireshark as that would stand out much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

mitm-proxy is great for stuff like this - http://crypto.stanford.edu/ssl-mitm/

You run it on your local machine in a console window, set your browser to use it as a proxy, and you can watch /log everything that your browser requests. It's a little noisy since it shows SSL hand-shaking and file contents, but you can filter that down. When you need to debug SSL communications it's invaluable to see those details though..

mitm-proxy is based on http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html which has more in the way of scripting capabilities.

Comment: Yeah I was using wireshark for a little bit and that was painful because there is so much HTTP/S noise.